# How can I form combinations out of a sentence

Tags: java

I am trying to produce an `array` of sentences from one original sentence, but also keep the order

for example

```
"The amazing spider man returns"
```

would produce 5 sentences

```
"The" 
"The amazing" 
"The amazing spider" 
"The amazing spider man" 
"The amazing spider man returns"
```

I started a loop but I cant figure out how to go about it

```
        String[] words=title.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        ???
        }
```

Comment: Create a string by concatenating the words from index 0 to index i, and print it.

Comment: @JBNizet so i need another loop inside for each sentence?

Comment: Or use a combination of `subString` and `indexOf`.

Comment: @code578841441 yes, you need a second loop to go from 0 to i.

Comment: @JBNizet He already has a loop that goes from 0 to i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do something like:

```
    String[] words=title.split(" ");
    String printWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        printWord += words[i] + " "; // Add the space for newly appended words
        System.out.println(printWord);
    }
```

The above, will just print the following

```
The 
The amazing 
The amazing spider 
The amazing spider man 
The amazing spider man returns
```

If you want to store it, just add it to a new array instead of calling `System.out.println()`.

Edit: Removed the quotes in the returned strings, because it doesn't print the quotes, of course :P

Edit2: If you want to add it to an array without the trailing white-space, just use [String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) as you add to the array.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
String title = "The amazing spider man returns";
String[] words = title.split(" ");
String[] result = new String[words.length];

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    if (i == 0) 
       result[i] = words[i];
    else 
       result[i] = result[i - 1] + " " + words[i];

}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Output

```
[The, The amazing, The amazing spider, The amazing spider man, The amazing spider man returns]
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/qZYx7N)